# MATLAB - Curve Fitting 1/x Function

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'd like to find a way to fit a curve to a specific functional form, namely:

y=constant/x

Is there a good way to do this? My data is just a set of (x,y) pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, try this.

You can rewrite this equation as: `y = c0 + c1*z` where c0 and c1 are the constants you want to solve for and `z = 1/x`.

If you have n points, you can write one equation for each pair:

```
y1 = c0 + c1*z1
y2 = c0 + c1*z2
...
yn = c0 + c1*zn
```

You've got an (n x 1) vector of known y values on the left hand side.  There's an (n x 2) matrix where the first column is all ones and the second column is the known vector of x values that multiplies a (2 x 1) vector of unknown coefficients c0 and c1.

Premultiply both sides by the (2 x n) transpose of the matrix and you'll have two equations for two unknown coefficients that you can solve easily.

Read [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/21983425/Least-Squares-Fit) for details.

Comment: This explanation does not actually fit the model the user asked for! There was NO constant term in the question, but you have added one, and then spent a lot of time explaining how to deal with it.

Comment: I know.  I think the constant is necessary.  I'd advise that the user let the data tell him/her whether the constant is zero or not.  You can also subtract it from the both sides to get the equation into the form that was first asked for, but it's helpful to know exactly what it is.

Comment: YOU think the constant is necessary? Its not YOUR model or YOUR data. You have no idea where the data comes from, or why an unconstanted model was chosen.

Comment: Hey woodchips, relax.  I'm answering the best I can based on what was posted.  You sound like you're taking this far too personally.  I added the constant exactly because I don't know.  As for the rest of the details, I added them because this is an educational site and somebody might want to know what MATLAB is doing on the inside.  Take a deep breath.

Comment: So why not add in a term for sin(x), or 1/x^2? Worse, you are suggesting the person use the normal equations to solve the problem, a terrible way to solve a regression problem! (That is what pre-multiplying by the transpose does.) backslash solves the problem without any premultiplication, and does it efficiently and accurately.

Comment: The answer to your first question is obvious and not worth addressing.  As for the second, you know best.  Your solution falls within the province of MATLAB, so it would be sensible to try it first.  We'll see if the OP comes back and actually accepts an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No reason to use anything more sophisticated than backslash, although the code inside backslash is quite sophisticated.

```
constant = (1./x(:))\y(:);
```

This does the linear regression for a model of the form y=constant/x. See that I inverted the elements of x using ./ and then applied backslash for the regression.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the optimization toolbox? If so, use the [lsqcurvefit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) function.

```
a=lsqcurvefit(@(a,x) a(1)./x,1,x,y);
hold on
plot(x,y,'o') %plot data
plot(x,a./x) %fit
```